# C# WinForms application runs slow from mapped network drive over VPN

Tags: c#, winforms, performance

We have a Winforms application that is located on a server.
In other words, the people start the application by a shortcut that points to the executable on the intranet. There where never any performance issues with this approach up till now.

The problem is that over a VPN the application loads extreme slow.
It takes 1 minute and 40 seconds just to show the main form.
All code in the main form in the Load and Show events are disabled to test the performance, and it still takes this long time just to load the form.
Also the mapped directory is set a trusted by windows.

The question is what could cause this slow loading over VPN ?
It seems to me that just loading the main form without any code is already slow.

The application uses DevExpress so there are lots off DLL's to load. Can that be the cause of this problem ?

I know this is not a good question for SO but I need some ideas in which direction to look for this problem.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37868587/c-sharp-windows-forms-application-runs-slow-from-mapped-network-drive) question here but the problem there was due to a bug in their code so it does not helps me

Comment: The app will have to download the exe and all DLLs on startup, that's why it will run slow.

Comment: Why not deploy the application as ClickOnce? When the application is first run it will be slow as the application will download, install in the Users\[user]\AppData folder. From then on as long as the application hasn't been redeployed it'll run from the local copy after checking with the network deployed version. To test your current issues, run the application from a local machine and also from a non-VPN network share then compare the start up speeds. I'd assume that the issue is with your VPN as it's got to encrypt all the traffic coming down from your network server then decrypt it locally

Comment: @HandbagCrab I never used `ClickOnce`before so I guess I have to start reading up on this

Comment: It's simple enough to set up and manage. Use the Publish tab on your project properties. I set mine up so that it's only available online and must be started from the setup.exe (which will be on your VPN'd network).

Comment: @HandbagCrab I have set it up as a ClickOnce application now and this fixes my problem and also keeps updating easy. If you write this as an answer i will accept it

Comment: I've added my comment with a little extra as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deploy the application as ClickOnce. When the application is first run it will be slow as the application will download, then install in the Users[user]\AppData folder. From then on as long as the application hasn't been redeployed it'll run from the local copy after checking with the network deployed version.

You can choose to have the application install locally so it has a start menu entry and can be removed with add/remove programs or you can have it only available online which means there's no start menu entry and it should be started from the setup.exe (I would assume this is the option you would want to go for so your users still start it from the VPN network location.